# Trying to Get FTP Address and use the input to pass to the next function in python

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, attributes

Having an issue with this and thought I would seek out some advice. I have a program that i'm creating which is a simple ftp login client. The following is the code that i'm stuck with :

code form the main module:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
from TKPractice import tk_method



def main():

    P = tk_method()

    print('Welcome to the FTP Directory Transfer Tool.')
    print('You can use this program to move Directories from one platform to 
        another')
    Connect(P)

def Connect(P):

     pingstatus =  P.GETFTP()
```

and code from the class i've created:

from tkinter import *

```
class tk_method(Tk):

  def __init__(self):


      Tk.__init__(self)


 def FTPSUBMIT(self):
     self.ftpentry = self.ftpentry.get()


 def GETFTP(self):
     root = Tk()
     root.title('GETFTP')
     root.wm_withdraw()
     self.ftpentry = Entry(self)
     self.submit = Button(self, text='Submit', command = self.FTPSUBMIT)

     self.submit.pack()
     self.ftpentry.pack()
     root.mainloop()





if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   run = tk_method()
   root.mainloop()
   root.wm_withdraw()
```

and the error i'm getting is  self.ftpentry = self.ftpentry.get()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'.

Please advise!

Comment: The error message seems mostly self-explanatory: `self.ftpentry` is a `str`.

Comment: `self.ftpentry = self.ftpentry.get()` <- that looks like a bad idea

Comment: Well the command to FTPSUBMIT has a few problems. First you are using `return` and that is going to return some value to the button and that is absolutely no use here. Next you are changing the variable name for your entry field to no longer referencing the entry field widget but rather a string of text you took from that widget. So that doesnt help.

Comment: I tried setting self.ftpentry to something different as well, however with no luck..I need to have a way to access the string that gets entered to Entry and use it in the main module as the ftp adress entered

Comment: Another issue I see is `root.wm_withdraw()`. Why are you doing this? You will never see your button or entry field.

Comment: Please provide a testable class and the imports you are using. I can see several problems with your code but its not easy to test without something we can copy pastes and run.

Comment: the root.wm_withdraw() is to kill the additional root window that pops up every time I run main.. This works fine. I'm getting the desired window with a prompt to enter the ftp address and a submit button. the problem is the functionality of the submit button.

Comment: Please provide more code. There are several things I need to address here. I can almost guarantee your `def GETFTP(self):` is not a good idea and 100% `def FTPSUBMIT(self):` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ill edit the original post to provide all of the contents for you- one second

Comment: I've Updated it Accordingly.. you should be able to test it now! name of the class i made is TKPractice.py for importing

Answer (score 0):

You code has several issues to address.

The first problem I see right away is your use of tkinters `Tk()` more than once. You should only ever create one instance of `Tk()` and then from there us a combination of `Frame` and `Toplevel` to create the rest of your interface.

Next do not use `root.wm_withdraw()` here to mask the problem you are seeing by using `Tk()` more than once. Keep in mind anything past the `mainloop()` wont run anyway until you close your program so that line is useless here.

For the most part this code can be reduced a lot and a cleaner version would look something like this.

```
import tkinter as tk


class tkMethod(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title('GETFTP')
        self.ftpentry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.submit = tk.Button(self, text='Submit', command=self.do_something)
        self.submit.pack()
        self.ftpentry.pack()

    def do_something(self):
        x = self.ftpentry.get()
        # do something with x.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run = tkMethod()
    run.mainloop()
```

Comment: Mike- thanks so much for your response! I am fairly new to Tk and your response has clarified a lot of things for me!!